# Multiple thumbnail images before upload with FileReader

Tags: javascript

I need help with making thumbnail images before uploading. I read a lot of questions here, but my problem (as I think) is a bit different.

So my code:

```js
function nextImg(num, name){
  var out = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12" id="img_'+num+'"><img class="img-responsive pad img-thumbnail" id="imgreal_'+num+'" src="#" alt="'+name+'"></div></div>';
  return out;
}

function showImgs(event){
  var files = event.target.files;
  if(files['length'] > 0){
    var div_edit = ""
    for(var i = 0; i < files['length']; i++){
      div_edit += nextImg(i,files[i]['name']);
    }
    document.getElementById("img_container").innerHTML = div_edit;

    for(var i = 0; i < files['length']; i++){
      var reader = new FileReader();
      console.log(i);
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        var num = "imgreal_"+i;
        console.log(num);
        var output = document.getElementById(num);
        output.src = reader.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[i]);
    }
  }else{
    document.getElementById('mainTAGs').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<form role = "form"  method = "post">
  <div class="container col-md-12 col-xs-12" id="img_container">

  </div>
</form>
```

So when I **iterate** over the opened images in the **second for cycle** the code gave all **reader.onload** function uniq **"imgreal_#" id**. 
When onload was **called** I log the id and it is always the **end criteria** of the for cycle.

*For* *example*, let say I want to upload 3 images, then all the getElementById in the reader.onload function called with "imgreal_3" instead of "imgreal_0"... "imgreal_2".

Any suggestion how to solve it? 
THX in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the common gotcha for JS. To make it work you should store somewhere current iteration value for the async functions to access it later. E.g. you can store the index in IIFE:

```
(function() {
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      var num = "imgreal_"+i;
      console.log(num);
      var output = document.getElementById(num);
      output.src = reader.result;
    }
  })(i)
```

The solution was:

```js
(function(n) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      var num = "imgreal_"+n;
      console.log(num);
      var output = document.getElementById(num);
      output.src = reader.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[n]);
})(i);
```